# Rug-Bug? Wrong position of rugs when plotting (plot.gam in library mgcv) smooth with factor by variable

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I observed a behavior in the `plot.gam` function concerning the positions of the rugs which seems weird to me. When plotting a smooth term with a factor by variable then the rugs are - as far as I can tell - not where they should be. I used R version 3.2.0 and mgcv 1.8-6.
So am I mistaken and `plot.gam` behaves the way it should and I just did not understand what it was doing? Or is there a bug in `plot.gam`?

Thanks for taking the time to have a look! Here is an example (the rugs as I expected them to occur will be plotted in red):

```
# produce a gam to work with
gamSim(4,n=400)->dat
gam(y~s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2, by=fac),data=dat) -> b

x11();par(mfrow=c(2,2))
# correct work for smooth terms without by variable
plot(b,select=1,main="x0 without by-variable")
rug(dat$x0,col="red")

# plot the three smooths for x2 - here the rugs differ from what I'd expect
for(i in 1:3){
  which(dat$fac == i) -> f
  plot(b,select=i+2,main=sprintf("x2; by=fac(%i)",i))
  rug(dat$x2[f],col="red")
}
```

Comment: any opinions, ideas or suggestions where to look to find an answer?